# I could run for ten miles

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs

a. Life is strange. Yesterday, I could run ten miles without a problem. Today I have a sprained ankle.

b. Life is strange. Yesterday, I was able to run ten miles without a problem. Today I have a sprained ankle.

Does (b) imply that I did run ten miles yesterday?

Could it be used as an equivalent to (a)?

I think (a) doesn't say whether I did run ten miles yesterday or not. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Sentence b. does not necessarily imply that you ran 10 miles yesterday. It could merely mean that you had the ability. So it *could* be used as a substitute for sentence a, but they're not equivalent.

"Be able to" has two meanings: *have the ability to do something* and *successfully do something*. In that particular context, it could have either meaning, so sentence b. is ambiguous.

Sentence a. is clear and b. is not, so while you could use b. in place of a., b. is not *equivalent* to a.